# Что такое сигнатура метода?

Tags: java, методы, терминология, java-8, спецификация

Что такое сигнатура метода и отличие от спецификация и контракта метода?

Comment: [Two of the components of a method declaration comprise the method signature— the method's name and the parameter types.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: сигнатура и спецификация это одно и то же?

Comment: В зависимости от того, где и как используется, может быть как одним и тем же, так и разными вещами

Comment: `private static void main(String[] args) throws Exception` - это сигнатура (спецификаторы доступа + тип + имя + параметры + checked-исключения)

Comment: @Vladimir, откуда такое предположение?

Comment: @ Grundy, Погорячился. Применительно к Java сигнатура обозначает имя метода и список его параметров. Следует, однако, иметь в виду, что сигнатура не включает в себя тип возвращаемого значения, поскольку он не используется в Java при принятии решения о перегрузке. Checked exception тоже является частью сигнатуры, насколько знаю. Поправьте, если ошибся.

Comment: Сигнатура метода включает только его имя и параметры, а спецификация - всё это плюс спецификаторы доступа, тип возвращаемого значения и указание на выброс проверяемого исключения, как сказал @Vladimir: `private static void main(String[] args) throws Exception`. Вот здесь упоминается ещё и указание пакета или класса, где определяется наш метод: http://faculty.salina.k-state.edu/tmertz/Java/031usingmethods/04methodspecifications.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Перевод из [docs.oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html):

> **Определение.**  Два компонента объявления метода включают ***сигнатуру
> метода*** - **имя метода** и **параметры**.
>
> Пример метода, описанного определения выше:
>
> ```
> calculateAnswer(double, int, double, double)
> ```

Cигнатура метода в сочетании с типом возвращаемого значения называется **контрактом метода**.

**Спецификация** метода может рассматриваться как документация для метода.

**Итог:**

`public void` **`moveTo(int x, int y)`** `throws IOException` — *сигнатура*

**`public void moveTo(int x, int y) throws IOException`** — *контракт*

*Спецификация* -

```
/**
 * Method - Description of the method
 * @param int x - description of parameter
 * @param int y - description of parameter
 * @return int - description of the return value
 **/
 int moveTo(int x, int y){...}
```

Answer (score 2):

Сигнатура метода — это имя метода плюс параметры (причем порядок параметров имеет значение). В сигнатуру метода не входит возвращаемое значение, а также бросаемые им исключения.

Comment: А спецификация???

Comment: Как понять спецификация? что ты под ним понимаешь?

Comment: @ArturVartanyan, так в этом вопрос и заключался ;)

Answer (score 1):

Весь код, который описывает метод, называется объявлением метода. Сигнатура метода включает название метода и типы параметров в определенном порядке.
Сигнатура метода включает в себя:

- Пространство имен и класс
- Идентификатор метода
- Порядок, тип, модификаторы(ref, out) параметров
  Но не включает:
- Тип возвращаемого значения
- Модификатор static
  Под спецификацией методологии понимается — объединение перечня средств и методов, применяющихся в специфике деятельности организации, со стороны теории и практики разработки, включая прототипирование. Методологией является формат объединения методов, средств и технологий, применяющихся во время всего жизненного цикла процесса разработки и прототипирования ПО в организации.